# Why did Cheech Marin have three roles in "From Dusk Till Dawn"?

Tags: from-dusk-till-dawn

In "From Dusk Till Dawn", three different characters were played by Cheech Marin.

There was no attempt to make the characters look significantly different.

Each time I first saw one of the characters, my first thought was "that looks like Cheech", but wasn't sure that it actually was.
I wasn't even sure that it was the same actor as before.

Was this an inside joke?  Are we supposed to think "all Mexicans look alike"? Or what?

Comment: why did peter sellers have multiple roles in Dr Strangelove? although it seems to be something calculated my understanding is that the producers figured the more of him in the film, the better and it just worked out very well, due to his versatility as an actor. who knows why this was done with Cheech.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that *From Dusk Till Dawn* is supposed to mimic a cheap, sleazy horror movie -- a genre Rodriguez and Tarantino revisited in [***Grindhouse***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grindhouse_(film)) -- it is possible that the makers decided to employ a tactic often used in such movies: the reuse of the same actor in multiple bit parts.

Note that the role of Carlos was originally intended for Erik Estrada.

In his book [***Quentin Tarantino FAQ: Everything Left to Know About the Original Reservoir Dog***](https://wiki.tarantino.info/index.php/Quentin_Tarantino_FAQ_-_Everything_left_to_know_about_the_original_Reservoir_Dog), **Dale Sherman** theorizes:

> Erik Estrada was to have appeared at the end of the movie as Carlos, the gangster that the Geckos went to the Tiny Twister to meet. Instead, when Estrada dropped out, it was decided that Cheech Marin, who had already played two other parts in the film, would be perfect in the role. **It does round out his appearances in the film, making his characters like a distortion of the farm/Oz characters being played by the same actors in the beginning, middle and end of *The Wizard of Oz*.**